# Why is capistrano acting up like this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am having an issue with my deploy

i ran cap deploy and got this

```
 Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
** [174.143.150.79 :: out] Permission denied (publickey).
** fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
command finished
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/transprint/releases/20110105034446; true"
servers: ["174.143.150.79"]
[174.143.150.79] executing command
```

here is my deploy.rb

```
set :application, "transprint"
set :domain, "174.149.150.79"
set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, false
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :app_path, "production"
set :rails_env, 'production'


set :repository,  "git@github.com:myname/something.git"
set :scm_username, 'deploy'

set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{application}"

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
```

please help

Comment: Can you post here what you have tried to do to solve/diagnose the issue so far?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Capistrano is sending commands to your server, running them as the "deploy" user, and one of those commands is attempting to connect to github. Please review:

http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/
(Check sections "SSH config" and "Permission denied (publickey)")

http://help.github.com/linux-key-setup/

Basically make sure you have:

- A github account
- SSH keys installed on 174.143.150.79
- The public SSH key setup on your github account profile